# How to sort array of numbers without gaps?

Tags: java, sorting

I have numbers like: 1,7,1,5 and I want to sort them without gaps between them (i.e.) 1,7,1,5 gets sorted to 1,1,2,3. (5 turns into 2; 7 turns into 3).

My code looks like this (works fine), but in some cases returns null pointer ex, or something like that :/

```
public void shake(Car[] c){
for(int i = 1; i < MaxPriority; i++)
   if(!isCarWithPriority(i, c))         
      for(int j = i; j < 10; j++)
         if(isCarWithPriority(j, c))    
            for(int k = 0; k < getCarsWithPriority(j, c).length; k++)  
               getCarsWithPriority(j, c)[k].setPriority(i);
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? Anyway, a first idea is just to sort the array (or list), then start replacing all the numbers since `1` by the non-gaps e.g. 1,1,5,7 => 1,1,2,3.

Comment: i have objects like cars. now each car have its priority represented by number. They will go in ascending order that means 1,1 together, than 5 then 7. In GUI i need to show order like positions - which ones are first, second etc.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try iterating through the numbers after sorting them. subtract 1st from 2nd if result is 0 then dont do anything else replace 2nd by first + 1 then compare 3rd one in the same way with second.. keep on till last number. you will get the desired output. This can be achieved by a single loop in java.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
 public static void main(String[] a) {
  Integer [] arr = {1,7,1,5};

  Arrays.sort(arr);
  for (Integer integer : arr) {
    System.out.println(integer);
}


for(int i=0; i< arr.length-1 ;i++){
    if(arr[i+1]-arr[i] ==0){
        continue;
    }else{
        arr[i+1] =arr[i]+1;
    }
}

System.out.println("--------------------");
for (Integer integer : arr) {
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```

}